# Error while executing custom commands to run python plugin in windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-3.x, cmd

I am trying to install a **model management framework** over python. 
I have **python 3.6 and windows 8.1**. I was able to successfully install the plugin. 
However, when I try to start the visualizer using the `studio ui` command, I get `'studio' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Most of the resources I have checked online show the installation on linux where this works, how do I get this to work on windows?

- [Site](https://www.studio.ml/>)
- [Documentation](http://docs.studio.ml/en/latest/README.html#installation)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/studioml/studio/blob/master/docs/README.rst)

I feel like I am missing something very basic here.

Comment: In which path are you trying to run `studio ui`? is `studio` an executable after all?

Comment: Check if studio appears in the output of `PATH` in the cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of figured it out. 
Apparently setuptools has the provision for specifying entry points. Sample file:

```
[console_scripts]
 mlflow=mlflow.cli:cli
```

> When pip (or another console_scripts aware installer) installs the distribution, it will create a command-line wrapper for each entry point.

So that if we type mlflow on the command line, it is automatically recognized.

So now I am able to run it by running the actual cli.py file with arguments, still need to figure out why this failed on my PC though.

Links: [Here](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/), [Here](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) and [Here](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html)